# $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed. Prove there exists a countable $E \subset F$, where $\bar{E} = F$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

$F \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed. Prove there exists a countable $E \subset F$, where $\bar{E} = F$. ($\bar E$ means closure of $E$)

---

*proof 1*

Let $E$ be the interior of $F$, which is open, by definition. Clearly, $\bar E = F$. Since every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written uniquely as the countable union of disjoint open intervals, and open intervals are opens sets, the set $E$ must be countable.

Note: That seems way too easy.

Comment: You are correct in being suspicious.

Comment: The sentence starting with "Clearly" is false. Consider the Cantor set, which is closed but has empty interior. Even simpler, consider $\{0\}$.

Comment: Try to execute your proof in the case $F=[0,1] \cup \{2\}$.  You should see it go wrong in at least 3 places.

Comment: @Bungo Just curious, is the Cantor set countable?

Comment: @Zduff It is not. :-)

Comment: No, the Cantor set is uncountable.

Comment: @Bungo Then the Cantor set is (1) closed, (2) has an empty interior, (3) is uncountable. Doesn't that mean that the statement I'm trying to prove is false?

Comment: It says that your method of proof won't work (i.e. beginning with the interior of $F$ isn't likely to be fruitful), but it doesn't mean that the statement is false.

Comment: @ Bungo So is the following reasoning false: The Cantor set is closed. The Cantor set contains no countable subsets such that the closure of any of those subsets is the Cantor set. Therefore, the statement to be proven above, is generally not true.

Comment: @Zduff Why do you claim Cantor set not to have countable dense subsets? In point of fact, it has.

Comment: Ahh, so every transcendental number in the Cantor set $C$ has convergent sequence of rational numbers contained in the Cantor set, meaning that if we take $E$ to be the union of all such rational sequences then $E$ is countable and the closure of $E = C$.

Comment: @Zduff The set of endpoints of the intervals removed in the construction of the Cantor set is countable (indeed, is a subset of $\mathbb Q$) and its closure is all of $C$.

Comment: Prove that there exists a number in the Cantor set that is not an element of a countable set.

Comment: @Zduff Are we making up statements? Every object is the element of some countable set, namely $\{x\}$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I wouldn't say it was "made up", maybe just ill-phrased. What I meant, I think, was: *construct an uncountable subset $A$ of the Cantor Set* in which $A$ does does not contain any algebraic numbers.

Comment: @Zduff Easily done.  Let $A$ be the set of all numbers whose base 3 representation is only 0s and 2s, and whose $n$'th 2 is either at position $2^{2^n}$ or $2^{2^n}+1$.  This is a subset of the Cantor set.  It is also a subset of the Liouville numbers, so they are all transcendental.  And you can construct a bijection between this set and the power set of the natural numbers so it is uncountable.  Oh and by the way, this is also a closed set.

Comment: Ah, yes, very intuitive for a measure theory beginner /s.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pointer to a valid proof.

The case of an empty set is trivial.

For a non-empty set, you can map each rational number onto the nearest element in F, breaking ties in favor of the smaller number.

Prove that the set of points E you have mapped the rationals onto is countable, is a subset of F, and that its closure includes every point in F.

Comment: So how about: for any isolated point of $F$ let $r \in R$ be the next largest rational number. Since $R \subset \mathbb{Q}$, $R$ is countable. Now, let $\hat F$ be the interior of the union of all intervals in $F$. $\hat F$ is countable since it's open $\implies \hat F \cup R = E$ is countable. $\bar E = E \cup \{\text{limit points of } E\} \implies \bar E = F$

Comment: @Zduff There is no "next largest rational number".

Comment: @Zduff There is no "next largest rational number".  But what there is is an enumeration of rational numbers.  So it is well defined to talk about the first rational number that meets a given condition.  That fact will be useful to generate a sequence $x_i$ from $E$ that converges to a given $x$ in $F$.  And with that I'll stop spoonfeeding you a potential answer to your homework problem.

Answer (score 2):

The comments have discussed several holes in your proof. Here is a *hint* for a proof to the general case, although you will have to make some extensions. Suppose $F$ was bounded, say $F\subset [a,b]$. We succesively take finite sets $E_i$, and at the end will put $E=\cup E_i$. Stage $0$ will be $E_0=\emptyset$. Once we have created $E_i$, we partition the interval $[a,b]$ into $i+1$ subintervals, $[a,a+\frac{b-a}{i+1}],[a+\frac{b-a}{i+1},a+2\frac{b-a}{i+1}],...,[a+i\frac{b-a}{i+1},b]$, and from each such subinterval we select one single point, $p_k\in F$, if $F$ intersects nontrivially with that subinterval. We then set 
$$
E_{i+1}=E_i\cup \{p_1,\dots,p_{i+1}\}.
$$
Can you show that in this case $E=\cup_i E_i$ is countable and satisfies $\overline{E}=F$?

Comment: This works, but I like avoiding the use of the axiom of choice when it is not needed.  Which is why I'd use a well-defined choice function rather than saying "for each subinterval we select one single point".

Comment: @btilly Sure, you could easily adapt the above proof to avoid choice, I just don't care too much about it