# Infinite closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be generated by its countable subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $F\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a infinite closed set. Prove that there exists a countable subset $E\subset F$ such that $\bar{E}=F$.

Comment: This property is called being hereditarily separable. It's implied by being second countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: For all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ let $B_n(x)$ be the ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ around $x$.

The cardinality of $\mathcal{O}=\{B_n(x):n\in\mathbb{N},x\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is the same as $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$ which is countable.

Now, Let $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{O}$ be the subset of all balls which intersect with $F$ (this clearly is countable).

For any $B\in\mathcal{B}$ pick an elemenet $x_B\in F$ that is also in $B$ (using the axiom of choice here). Let $E =\{x_B:B\in\mathcal{B}\}$.

Can you show that $E$ is dense in $F$?

Comment: Thank you for your hint.It is trivial that $\bar{E}\subset F$,so it suffices to prove the converse.For any $a\in F$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a\in B_n(x)$ and $B_n(x)$ contains a point in $E$. So the dense is proved?

Comment: You don't need the axiom of choice. In fact, in practice one usually wants to see that selecting points in settings such as this can be done explicitly.

Comment: @FengShao The point is that for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can choose $n$ sufficiently large and $y$ sufficiently close to $a$ so that $x_{B_n(y)}$ is more than $\varepsilon$ close to $a$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thanks for your comment. I tried to think about that but I don't see how I can choose the points explicitly (I have no knowledge about $F$ besides that it's closed).

Comment: @FengShao It looks like your question has already been asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929572/f-subset-mathbbr-is-closed-prove-there-exists-a-countable-e-subset-f?rq=1

Comment: @Yanko I forgot to point it out, but in my previous comment, letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ will work, I think.

Comment: @FengShao yes that's the idea.

Comment: @Yanko OK.....Thanks for telling me. But I really think your hint is more valid than answers there.

Comment: @FengShao Wow thanks, I'm glad.

Answer (score 5):

Let $X$ be a second countable space and $\mathcal B$ be a countable basis for its
topology.

For a closed subset $F$, pick an element of each $U\cap F$ for $U\in\mathcal B$, provided it is nonempty. These elements form a countable set $E$ with $F=\overline E$.