# An infinite closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that every infinite closed subset of real numbers is the closure of a countable set.

This question was discussed here:
[$F \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed. Prove there exists a countable $E \subset F$, where $\bar{E} = F$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2929572/809050)

Please verify my proof:
Let $A$ be a closed subset then we can express $A$ as countable intersection of open intervals. $A=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$. Then $\cap_n( I_n \cap \mathbb{Q})$ is countable and whose closure is $A$.

Can we extend this for higher dimension?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not correct. $A=\{0,1\}$ is a closed set which cannot be written as  countable intersection of open intervals. In fact no closed set which is not connected can be written this way.

Comment: Sir if we replace the word open interval by open set?

Comment: Can you justify the last line in your proof? That is something that cannot be taken for granted.

Comment: Sorry sir! I have done some mistakes. The closure is a subset if $A$.